# Store cell in range, and then delete in 1 go

Tags: excel, vba

i have created the following code, it aims at delete the empty cell in column R that exists between data, the problem comes to how to store the blank cell in range, any advise?

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim lastRow_1 As Long
Dim counter_1 As Long
Dim rng_1 As Range, aCell As Range

lastRow_1 = Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

MsgBox lastRow_1

counter_1 = 1

For counter_1 = 1 To lastRow_1

    If Trim(Range("R" & counter_1).Value) = "" Then

       Set aCell = Range("R" & counter_1)

       rng_1 = Union(rng_1, aCell)

    End If

Next


    rng_1.Delete xlUp
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `rng_1` being set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming R200 is the last cell in the range

```
range("R1:R200").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete
```